# id in descending S.N in ascending

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want my id to be in descending order but want my S.No to be in ascending order.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order BY  id) [S.N], id,itemname,unit,price 
from items 
ORDER BY id desc , [S.N]
```

[image: Picture of the database]

Comment: Your query looks perfect

Comment: Or provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi,I've added pic to the question,.i want my s.no to be in asc but id to be in desc when i use this query both my s.n and id become desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `desc` to your window function:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order BY  id desc) [S.N], 
    id, 
    itemname,
    unit,
    price 
from items 
ORDER BY id desc
```